# listview builder RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range

Tags: flutter, list, dart, listview

I have a list inside a `ListView.builder`.
Inside the list are dates. I want to compare the date on the current index with the next date (index + 1). If it is different, I want to add a headline:

```dart
if (DateTime(food[index].todaysDate.day) != DateTime(food[index + 1].todaysDate.day)) ...[
     Divider(color: Colors.blue),
     Text("NewDay"),
     Divider(),
],
```

But when I do it like that I get a "`RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range`". It is running out of range because of the `index + 1`. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becareful about the last index of your list,
imagine that your list has 9 indexes and you do not have the tenth one.
if you want to compare be sure that the `index` is less that the `length - 1` in your condition:

```
if (index < (food.length -1) && DateTime(food[index].todaysDate.day) != DateTime(food[index + 1].todaysDate.day)) ...[
                                Divider(color: Colors.blue),
                                Text("NewDay"),
                                Divider(),
                              ],
```

happy coding...

Comment: Ah, addition: To cover really everything I had to add an or condition with the other side, so "-": `|| index < (food.length - 1) &&
                                    DateTime(food[index].todaysDate.month, food[index].todaysDate.day) !=
                                        DateTime(food[index - 1].todaysDate.month, food[index -1].todaysDate.day))` Otherwise it wouldn't compare the last index value

Comment: please explain it more. tell me the exact conditions that you've added. those conditions that you've added may change the situation

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the value of `index` is always one less than the maximum valid value. The easiest way to do this is to wrap your expression in another if statement:

```dart
//If the current index is less than the maximum index (length - 1), then there is a later index to compare to.
if (index < (food.length - 1)){
    if (DateTime(food[index].todaysDate.day) != DateTime(food[index + 1].todaysDate.day)){
    ....//Rest of code here
    }
}
```

This way, it won't check if there isn't a later date to compare to and you should avoid the RangeError.